# Is there a way to use the "Properties" Window also for cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am curious whether I can get a properties window for cells select in Excel. With "properties window" I mean the same on the Developer interface uses for properties of entities in VBA. I use AutoCAD a lot and have gotten used to being able to see and edit all attributes of an entity through the properties window. It would be quite handy if I had all info of a cell available in Excel too.

Comment: Nothing is built-in (AFAIK) but it should be straightforward to write a macro that opens a userform which displays the various properties of the selected cell (or at least the ones that  you are interested in), and which can edit those properties. Sounds like a good project. If you have any problems writing the code, post another question which shows your attempt and discusses the problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman .................interesting idea...............

Answer (score 3):

The **content** is displayed in the Formula Bar.  The **formatting** can be displayed by touching:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>:

[image]

This is **not** a complete set of Properties. *(Comments are displayed by mouseover,etc.)*

Comment: This might be what OP had in mind, although it would certainly be nice to have a drop-down menu that would give you everything in one place.

Comment: @JohnColeman  It would be a neat project.........easy to start........lot of effort to complete.

Comment: I meant this to be in the format as we are used from VBA, i.e one long list with collapsible sections. This is a floating box which remains open the whole time, the benefit being that you can quickly check and get an overview of all data, how it is stored.